# Javascript Changing variable to input or dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have here a piece of code and into my canvas it shows 10 triangles going into a circle but my problem is that the variable is 10 (var aantal = 10). I would like a dropdown menu where people can say how many triangles there have to rotate in the canvas.

here is how it looks like now: http://21248.hosts.ma-cloud.nl/bewijzenmap/periode4/SCT/10x3hoek/index.html

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
<header>Your name</header>

<script src="utils.js"></script>
<script src="triangle.js"></script>
<script>
window.onload = function () {
      var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
      context = canvas.getContext('2d');

      var omlaag = false;
      var links = false;
      var omhoog = false;
      var speed = 0.5;
      var posX = 0;
      var posY = 0;
      var lifeCycle = 1;

      var aantal = 10;
      var triangle = [];

      for (var i = 0; i < aantal; i++){
          triangle[i] = new Triangle;
          triangle[i].xLeft = 20 + 30*i;
          triangle[i].yLeft = 20 + 20*i;

      }

      (function drawFrame () {
         window.requestAnimationFrame(drawFrame, canvas);
         context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

       for (var i = 0; i < aantal; i++){      

         triangle[i].x = posX;
         triangle[i].y = posY;

          switch (lifeCycle) {
            case 1:
                posX += speed;
                if (posX >= canvas.width) {
                    lifeCycle = 2;
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                posY += speed;
                if (posY >= canvas.height) {
                    lifeCycle = 3;
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                posX -= speed;
                if (posX <= 0) {
                    lifeCycle = 4;
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                posY -= speed;
                if (posY <= 0) {
                    lifeCycle = 1;
                }
                break;
            }
           triangle[i].draw(context);
       }           

      }());
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  window.onload = function () {
     var aantal =prompt("Enter how many triangles to rotate?");

          var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
          context = canvas.getContext('2d');

          var omlaag = false;
          var links = false;
          var omhoog = false;
          var speed = 0.5;
          var posX = 0;
          var posY = 0;
          var lifeCycle = 1;

          // aantal = 10;
          var triangle = [];

          for (var i = 0; i < aantal; i++){
              triangle[i] = new Triangle;
              triangle[i].xLeft = 20 + 30*i;
              triangle[i].yLeft = 20 + 20*i;

          }

          (function drawFrame () {
             window.requestAnimationFrame(drawFrame, canvas);
             context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

           for (var i = 0; i < aantal; i++){      

             triangle[i].x = posX;
             triangle[i].y = posY;

              switch (lifeCycle) {
                case 1:
                    posX += speed;
                    if (posX >= canvas.width) {
                        lifeCycle = 2;
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    posY += speed;
                    if (posY >= canvas.height) {
                        lifeCycle = 3;
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    posX -= speed;
                    if (posX <= 0) {
                        lifeCycle = 4;
                    }
                    break;
                case 4:
                    posY -= speed;
                    if (posY <= 0) {
                        lifeCycle = 1;
                    }
                    break;
                }
               triangle[i].draw(context);
           }           

          }());
    };
```

Comment: it ask for promp...to enter a number and then you can have that many triangles to rotate

Answer (score 0):

Simple way add `input` and  change value as user changes

```
 <input type="number" min="0" id="triangle" >
```

Just press `ENTER` .....
then Javascript

```
var triangle=document.querySelector('#triangle');

triangle.addEventListener('change',function(e){
   aantal = this.value
});
```